# Coordinate grid display on a rotated map

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, coordinates, grids-graticules

I have a series of maps that require me to rotate my data frame within my layout screen (north "rarely" points up in these maps).  I ONLY want to show east coordinates on the top/bottom and ONLY north coordinates on the sides (see image below).  How do I do this?  I would expect to see such an option when I go inside of properties menu under "grids", but I'm not having any luck.  I'm using ArcView 10.  Can anyone help?  If I haven't articulated what I'm trying to accomplish very well, feel free to edit my question. 
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: @ everyone - the only means I've found to get past this problem is to convert my grid to a graphic, select & ungroup it, and then to manually delete the tics & coordinates I want removed.  NOT very efficient!!  A better suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: any chance you do not have service pack 3 for arcgis10 installed? I had similar grid issues and once service pack 3 was installed it seemed to correct it.

Comment: No .... I have SP2. If ESRI has rolled out SP3 I imagine we'll be updating our software very soon though. I've just been converting to a graphic & deleting the UTM coordinates I want removed. There should be an option to only display X on the X-axis & Y on the Y-axis. It could see it being confusing to the average "non-GIS savvy" map reader (even though it's quite clear to us GIS-folk).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think a new release or service pack will resolve the issue, though you could always add it to [ideas.arcgis.com](http://ideas.arcgis.com) and see what happens. Perhaps an alternative approach might work for you though: Add two grids, one with north-south only lines/labels and the other with east-west only and make each in a different style/font/colour.

This will address the concern of reader confusion without having to take data away (because a different sort of confusion arises when one traces a line to the neatline and there is no corresponding number).

[image: close up of grids and labels intersecting neatline, each axis in a different colour]

Caution: I crashed arcmap a couple of times by entering 0 into the axis interval field during the initial grid creation when using the wizard. No troubles editing the number to 0 afterwards though.

Comment: +1 Matt - A feasible solution, and we actually discussed a similar approach at one point.  There are no grid lines on these maps (far too busy with information) but we did discuss the possibility of using 2 different text colours as a means of differentating the Eastings from the Northings.  I suspect (judging by the lack of feedback on my question) that this is the closest I'm going to get to the answer I wanted.  That said, I've awarded this one to you.  Cheers

Comment: @Dano, glad to help! I lean towards different styling (typeface/bold/italic) than differing colours, so as to keep more colour choices available for map items. I used colours in the graphic to exaggerate the point.